# Spring Security-Reload my security.xml on edit

Tags: spring, security

I am using Spring Security in my project. I have a situation where I need to change the pattern attribute in itercept-url tag on runtime. For this I have to again restart the tomcat server and in turn takes a lot of time for me to test my changes.

Does Spring have a solution where the security.xml file is reloaded when I edit it in my web application, without restarting my server. Please provide some pointers for the same as I am new to Spring Framework.

Any link to a step by step tutorial will certainly help a lot.

Thanks in advance.

Divyang Agrawal

Answer (score 0):

Use spring annotation rather than using xml configuration. so by using annotation you do not required tomcat restart after changing the source code.

you can find simple tutorial for how to use annotation based spring security here **[Link](http://www.mkyong.com/spring-security/spring-security-hello-world-annotation-example/)**